# Is there a Stack Overflow-like site for designers?

Tags: support, asking-questions, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How about a designer focused site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7129/how-about-a-designer-focused-site)

Is there a Stack Overflow-like site for designers? Where I can ask about all things Photoshop, Illustrator, Lightwave, &c.?

The question I need to ask: How can I batch insert 200 names into a GIF file and export each one individually? This is going to be used for e-mail signatures since Outlook 2007 no longer supports HTML signatures.

Comment: Go to the stackoverflow home page.  Scroll all the way to the bottom.  Where it says "doctype.com", click on that.

Comment: Gang I don't think it's very friendly to close a question without taking a second to drop in a comment indicating why.  (I don't disagree that this question isn't a Stackoverflow question, but it's not a *bad* question.)

Comment: @Pointy: This wasn't closed, it was migrated. And either way there's a big banner under the question explaining the close reason (or in this case the location the question was migrated to), so there really is no need for comments beyond that.

Comment: I'm all for leaving comments when closing questions, but *migrating* doesn't necessarily need one (even though it's nice).

Comment: You might lucky in http://doctype.com

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7129/how-about-a-designer-focused-site and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46869/is-there-a-stackoverflow-type-site-for-designers-creatives.

Answer (score 1):

With "StackOverflow-like" you most probably meant to say "StackExchange-based", targeting on the underlying webapp engine providing a platform for Questions and Answers database.

Well, in the [list of all StackExchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) I can find only one: [**Creative Query**](http://www.creativequery.com/). It's only not really active.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it would be a great thing, a SO-like site for:

- 3D modellers (Maya, Blender...)
- Video/audio editing (Adobe Premiere, Final Cut Pro, Avid, Sony Vegas...)
- Photoshop/GIMP and all other photo editing/creating stuff

There are certainly enough users, and very much so enough "how do I" questions.

I found [this on area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265/photography-and-photographic-editing), but don't like it being solely photography.

Answer (score 0):

http://tutsplus.com is a great site for all things design. But they focus more on actual tutorials and not the HOW TO aspect of using the application to get something right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want such a site you could always propose it on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), if someone else hasn't already.  Actually the proposed [Graphic Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design) site might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments before migration, you might want to try [DocType](http://www.doctype.com/).  It's not part of the immediate SO family, but it was modeled after SO with permission, and is a member of the League of Justice.